# LXML escaped character conversion

Tags: python, xml, escaping, character, lxml

Ok so first of all I have a script which is operating on a dos file formatted XML file. That is, the file has \r\n line terminations. Furthermore, the XML file I am operating on has some newlines embedded within some attributes. The XML editor which produced the XML encodes these newlines as: `&#xD;&#xA;`

I am using LXML and some of the processing I am doing changes these text attributes into XML elements. The problem I am seeing is that the text blocks with the newlines in them end up as elements but with some crud just before the newline. I.e. `&#13;` which, by the way is equivalent to `&#xD;` as I understand it.

Now, this, to me seems to be an issue in that the script I am executing is executing within a linux environment and it dumps out a linux file formatted file.

It appears to me as if LXML is correctly seeing that `&#xA` is an escaped newline  and changes this for an actual newline in the destination element. It seems to be forgetting about the `&#xD` though.

I created a test xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<element1>
  <element2 value="0"/>
  <element3 documentation="Some documentation.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Some more documentation"/>
</element1>
```

And here is a sample python file to do some manipulation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import argparse
import sys

import lxml.etree as ET
xml = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = xml.getroot()
elem = root.find('element3')
doc = ET.SubElement(elem, 'documenation')
doc.text = elem.get('documentation')
xml.write('out.xml', encoding='UTF-8', method="xml", pretty_print=True)
```

Here is the output:

```
 <element1>
  <element2 value="0"/>
  <element3 documentation="Some documentation.&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;Some more documentation"><documenation>Some documentation.&#13;
&#13;
Some more documentation</documenation></element3>
</element1>
```

I guess my question is this, is this how you guys would expect this to work?
I would have thought that in the documentation element, we would no longer have the  references any more. 
It seems a bit inelegant if I have to now do some grepping for these extraneous CR characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is precisely how I'd expect it to work. While XML processors are required to normalize line-endings on input, there is no requirement to normalize line endings on output.

If I were in your shoes, I'd fix the code that generated that XML to avoid putting carriage returns in attributes. Failing that, I'd try:

```
doc.text = elem.get('documentation').replace('\r','')
```

Comment: Is it illegal to put carriage returns in an attribute? Unfortunately it is too late to modify how the database was populated and the attributes in question contain textual elements which do contain a certain amount of formatting such as line breaks. The tool which I used to input the data was xml notepad.
Can you please elaborate on what you mean by normalizing line endings? It just strikes me as odd that if a tool is going to change the representation of the data, it doesn't change the data itself or at least the intention which is what seems to be happening here.

Comment: What I did in the end is follow your recommendation. I did a global replace from \r\n to \n which is what I want and for that I will mark this answered. Thanks.